# Merging 2 images in Java increase size

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I have 2 images to be merged that are 810KB & 850KB in size (Jpegs). When I use the following method, the resulting 'merged' *PNG* images size is 16.4MB (on disk). Why is this the case and how can I reduce the size while having the merged image be a PNG file?

```
public ImageOverlay mergeImage(BufferedImage baseImage, BufferedImage mergeImage, int padding) {
    // create the new image, canvas size is the max. Of both image sizes
    int w = baseImage.getWidth() + padding + mergeImage.getWidth();
    int h = Math.max(baseImage.getHeight(), mergeImage.getHeight());
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // paint both images, preserving the alpha channels
    Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(mergeImage, baseImage.getWidth() + padding, 0, null);
    baseImage = combined;
ImageIO.write(baseImage, "png", new File(fileLocation));
}
```

Comment: What type of images is it ?

Comment: Then write them not as png, but jpeg. At the end do `g.dispose()` to prevent resource leakage.

Comment: This topic may be related to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349378/merged-two-images-4-times-the-size-how-do-i-reduce-the-file-size